# Disable input and score count in pause menu?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, pause

I need some sort of an if statement, which allows me to **disable any input and incrementing score while I'm in the pause menu**.
The problem is that I don't really understand this kind of pausing code, I'm "used to" the regular boolean one.
So, I show all the code.

First script:

```
public enum GameState
{
    Gameplay,
    Paused
}
```

Second script:

```
public class GameStateManager
{
    private static GameStateManager _instance;

    public static GameStateManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new GameStateManager();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public GameState CurrentGameState { get; private set; }

    public delegate void GameStateChangeHandler(GameState newGameState);
    public event GameStateChangeHandler OnGameStateChanged;

    private GameStateManager()
    {

    }

    public void SetState (GameState newGameState)
    {
        if (newGameState == CurrentGameState)
            return;

        CurrentGameState = newGameState;
        OnGameStateChanged?.Invoke(newGameState);
    }
}
```

Third script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PauseGame()
    {
        GameState currentGameState = GameStateManager.Instance.CurrentGameState;
        GameState newGameState = currentGameState == GameState.Gameplay
            ? GameState.Paused
            : GameState.Gameplay;

        GameStateManager.Instance.SetState(newGameState);
    }
}
```

And as last, here is what I've done in my character movement script:

```
    void Start()
    {
        GameStateManager.Instance.OnGameStateChanged += OnGameStateChanged;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameStateManager.Instance.OnGameStateChanged -= OnGameStateChanged;
    }

    private void OnGameStateChanged (GameState newGameState)
    {
        enabled = newGameState == GameState.Gameplay;
    }
```

This is all the code. Where and how am I supposed to write the input and score increment "blockings"?
I am so sorry for this being so long and I am grateful if you read all this! :)

Comment: Why is your `GameStateManager` not simply a `static class`? And whether you use a flag or enum should make little difference in how you treat it in the end .. except a flag would be way easier to invert in the `PauseController.PauseGame`

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1. Where you have your score/input logic, you can check, if the state is Gameplay, and if not - just return. Like this:

```
if (currentGameState == GameState.Gameplay) 
{
     CheckInput();
     UpdateScore();
}
else
{
     return;
}
```

Another approach (better) is to have score update and input logic incorporated into current GameState. But you should rework your code:

You need the base GameState class:

```
public abstract class GameStateBase
{
     public abstract void UpdateScore();
     public abstract Vector2 GetInput();
}
```

Then you need 2 actual states, inherited from it:

```
public class GameStateGameplay : GameStateBase
{
     public override void UpdateScore()
     {
          //---- DO SOME SCORE LOGIC HERE
     }
     public override  Vector2 GetInput()
     {
          // for example, your input is mouse position:
          return Input.mousePosition;
     }
}

public class GameStatePause : GameStateBase
{
     public override void UpdateScore()
     {
          //---- DO NOTHING HERE, BECAUSE ITS PAUSE
     }
     public override  Vector2 GetInput()
     {
          //---- RETURN ZERO HERE, BECAUSE ITS PAUSE
          return Vector2.zero;
     }
}
```

Then, you need your state manager, simplified:

```
public class StateMachine
{
     public GameStateBase CurrentState;

     public void SetGameplay()
     {
          CurrentState = new GameStateGameplay();
     }

     public void SetPause()
     {
          CurrentState = new GameStatePause();
     }
}
```

Finally, where you doing your actual game logic, you can get current state - whatever it is, pause or gameplay - and let it handle your things:

```
private StateMachine _myStateMachine; // you can get it as a singleton instance, or somewhat else...

private void Update()
{
     _myStateMachine.CurrentState.UpdateInput();
    
     // assume, this is some PlayerObject:
     transform.position += _myStateMachine.CurrentState.GetInput(); // Gameplay will return you actual input, and your object will move. Pause returns always zero, and object wouldn't move.
}
```

WHy it's better? Because this way you can implement as many states as you want. You can not create a new state everytime, but create it once, store references, and then just assign one to _current. You can make states as MonoBehaviours, and state machine too. It's highly recommended to learn about state machines, because it's used widely in game development.

Comment: For this kind of states it would be way better than to use `ScriptableObject` instead of `MonoBehaviour` .. I like to call this approach "Scriptable Behaviour" so you can even use it across multiple scenes and assets

Answer (score 0):

After hours of reading about state machines, I don't feel like I got any more into the topic.
I understand now why is it optimal and for what its suggested use is. But I totally don't get the use of it in code.
Sorry for the slow tempo, but can you show me how exactly do I have to implement this statement:

```
if (currentGameState == GameState.Gameplay) 
{
     CheckInput();
     UpdateScore();
}
else
{
     return;
}
```

Into my actual (for example) movement code?

```
void CheckInput()
{
    //if first input then ignore
    if (firstInput)
    {
        firstInput = false;
        return;
    }
    //here is where I want to implement, so if the game is paused, ChangeDirection will not play
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        ChangeDirection();
    }
}
```

Sorry again for having these basic questions, but I am not an expert (I bet you didn't realize it yet :D) and this is also so much different from a simple boolean.

Comment: Ok, forgot about state machines (for now), and stick to approach 1. You already have the state, state changeing and state checking implemented in your initial code. Also, you have CheckInput() function implemented. So, the only thing you need is to call CheckInput, when state is "Gameplay", and don't call it, when the state is "Pause". In your Update() function, put the check I wrote first: `if (currentGameState == GameState.Gameplay) 
{
     CheckInput();
     UpdateScore();
}
else
{
     return;
}`

Comment: In this case, when the state is "Gameplay", your CheckInput() is called, and when the state is any other ("Pause"), it does nothing, just returns.